# Excel how to check the correspondance of two columns

Tags: excel

I would like to check which value in the adjacent row corresponds to my column. I tried to use the VLOOKUP function as follows:

[Excel VBA - how to automatically correspond ranges to value](https://superuser.com/questions/1322049/excel-vba-how-to-automatically-correspond-ranges-to-value)

but with no results.

If you look at my picture below:

[image]

I am interested in column F (Postcode) and G (Key). Each postcode corresponds to the specified key. Because they were repeatable I did a separate list, calculating all of them manually. Now I would like to assign a proper postcode to each key mentioned in this list (column M). How can I do this?

I tried also the XLOOKUP function

```
=XLOOKUP(M2,G:G,F:F)
```

but in my cell I can see the #NAME only.

Seeing the basic XLOOKUP examples I think everything should be alright

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function

However is that the reason, that my values are repeatable? Should I remove duplicates first?
I need to have the proper postcode next to the string in the M column (in the target column L). How can I do that?

Comment: If you don't have access to `XLOOKUP` yet, then use `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

Comment: the INDEX/MATCH are separate functions I see:
https://exceljet.net/index-and-match
how can I combine them in one?

Comment: `=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(M2,G:G,0))`.

Comment: @BigBen you are great! Thanks, A LOT!

Comment: @BigBen, sounds like an answer...

Comment: @MaciejLos yes indeed. This is what I was after.